# Dynamic Dropdown Option List on CloudPage

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I have a preference center with a State/Province field and a matching variable listed as a dropdown selection list on the cloudpage.

Wondering how I can achieve a pre-selection based on the existing value in the data extension, if it is not null.

I have most of it working (ie. if I select CO, it'll write into the Data Extension once submitted), but it won't show the existing value in the dropdown since I have a placeholder "State/Province" pre-selected.

```
<select id="state" name="state" value="%%v(@state)%%"> 
                 <option value="" selected disabled hidden>State/Province</option>
                 <option value="AL">AL</option>
                 <option value="AK">AK</option>
                 <option value="AR">AR</option>
```

Comment: Please, could you provide code for what you've done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally do this by creating a data extension that contains all the states inside of it, along with a column of 'Secret' that always has a value of 1.

E.g.

```
State  |  Secret
 NJ    |    1
 PA    |    1
 CA    |    1
 AK    |    1
```

This will allow me to do a FOR loop to create the options for your select tag.

I recommend this approach as the option tag will need to include an `IIF` statement and having around 50 instances of the same `IIF` statement is opening it up to risk of human error and is also a maintenance nightmare if you ever need to edit it.

Below is what I would recommend to allow your select to have a default option of 'State/Province' if there is no state (or value does not match) as well as have the correct state option pre-populate if it exists inside the DE you created.

```
<select id="state" name="state"> 
%%[

SET @StateDE = "StateDE"
/* Create a DE with all your state choices in one column (as pkey) */
/* and then a second column named 'Secret' with a value of '1' */


SET @yourState = AttributeValue("yourState")
/* Pulls in the value of 'state' from your sendable DE */


/* Verify if there is a value in @yourState and if that value matches an existing state choice */
IF NOT EMPTY(@yourState) THEN

    SET @stateLookup = LookupOrderedRows(@StateDE, DataExtensionRowcount(@StateDE), "State ASC", "State", @yourState)
    /* Orders alphabetically for your dropdown. Also limits output to max value of DE */

    IF Rowcount(@stateLookup) > 0 THEN

        SET @statematch = 1

    ENDIF

ENDIF

]%%

%%[ IF NOT @statematch THEN]%%

    <option value="" selected disabled hidden>State/Province</option>

%%[ENDIF]%%

%%[
/* Build Rowset to contain values for Select input */
SET @stateRowset = LookupRows(@StateDE, "Secret", "1")
SET @stateRowcount = Rowcount(@stateRowset)


If @stateRowcount > 1 THEN

    FOR @i=1 TO @stateRowcount DO

        SET @stateRow = Row(@stateRowset, @i)
        SET @state = Field(@stateRow, "State")
]%%
    <option value="%%=v(@state)=%%" %%=IIF(@yourState == @state, "selected","")=%%>%%=v(@state)=%%</option>

%%[

    NEXT @i
]%%
```